# Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My application is not starting because of this error `"Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerAutoConfiguration"` .

How can I solve this issue?

The entire error I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.DefaultFeignLoadBalancedConfiguration.feignClient
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    
    
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCircuitBreakerAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:649)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1605)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:167)
    
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/client/circuitbreaker/CircuitBreakerFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
```

My Pom

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>

</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud-netflix-core.version>2.2.6.RELEASE</spring-cloud-netflix- core.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The ultimate reason is: _"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerFactory"_... In other words, you're missing something from the classpath.

Comment: What about this error Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.DefaultFeignLoadBalancedConfiguration.feignClient

Comment: It is all part of the same exception stacktrace. In general, the real problem is at the bottom, and the top is informing you of the ultimate result for your application (in this case, not being able to correctly configure Feign client. In other words, if you want to find out the cause of the problem, you need to read back through the "Caused by:" parts.